# Holes in My Mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigging, armature

So I have this bear mesh I made. Set up the armature and weights. Now I'm realizing that if I move the bones in certain ways these holes open up. How do I close these up? I don't know if it's related but I used a mirror modifier.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In edit mode select all and press W and choose Remove Doubles. It should fix the problem. If not, try it again, but increase Merge Distance.[image: merge distance]

In your particular example, when the mirror modifier is not yet applied you have to enable Clipping in mirror modifier, select middle edge loop and move it towards the center of the mesh on Y axis until you won't be able to move it anymore.It will fix the problem.
[image]

Comment: Hey man. Thanks for responding. I actually already tried removing doubles and I just tried merge distance but I don't really know how high to go with it. When i raise it the holes get bigger. I also uploaded the blend file

Comment: Hey, I tried the clipping and moving the edges and it worked. I'm actually not sure what middle edge select is, but I used shift+w to move the edges together

Comment: middle edge loop is an edge loop, that's in the middle of the mesh(including mirror reflection) and select is just select.