# Animation: mesh is split at seam points

Tags: animation, uv

[image]

This is what I have done :

1.mark seams -> unwrap mesh for uv map (for texture map etc.)

2. make armature -> parent mesh to armature -> move bone

The problem is that the mesh 'opens' at the seams I set before while animating.

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. Did you try to remove doubles ? (In Edit mode select all and press W > Remove Doubles). Maybe related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66036/holes-in-my-mesh.